# Ejecutar automáticamente un método al desplegar una aplicación en JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación del lado del servidor la misma que cuenta con servicios web para su comunicación con el lado del cliente. 
Cuando despliego la aplicación necesito que un método se ejecute automáticamente, este método lo que hará es inicializar ciertos parámetros en la base de datos y también inicializará una tarea programada con la librería timerTask. 
No se como hacer que se ejecute este método al desplegar la app,  hasta el momento lo que he hecho es crear un método web  que invoque a este método y para que se ejecute tengo que entrar como un cliente e invocar a este método web pero la idea es que este método se ejecute automáticamente

Espero su ayuda gracias!!

Comment: Hola USER, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También puedes revisar [como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usar Static Blocks
Haz esto. Inicia una clase con ellos dentro. Para que veas lo que digo te dejo un par de ejemplos

```
public class Ejemplo1{
    //Esto es un static block
    {System.out.println("Bloque estatico 1");}
    //Esto es un segundo static block
    {System.out.println("bloque estatico 2");}

    private String test;
    public Ejemplo1(String prueba){
        System.out.println("Dentro del constructor del objeto");
        this.test=prueba;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Primera linea del programa ANTES de que se instancie el objeto de la clase");
        Ejemplo1 prueba = new Ejemplo1("4");
        System.out.println("Linea despues del objeto ha sido instanciado, el constructor fue llamado para poder tener que instanciarlo");
    }
}

Output:
 Primera linea del programa ANTES de que se instancie el objeto de la clase
Bloque estatico 1
bloque estatico 2
Dentro del constructor del objeto
Linea despues del objeto ha sido instanciado, el constructor fue llamado para poder tener que instanciarlo
```

Con este ejemplo te dejo claro que la primera linea del programa corre si o si PERO con este segundo quiero que veas como con tan solo crear un objeto puedes hacer que sus bloques estaticos se ejecuten SI O SI tambien

```
public class Ejemplo2{
    //Esto es un static block
    {System.out.println("Bloque estatico 1");}
    //Esto es un segundo static block
    {System.out.println("bloque estatico 2");}

    private String test;
    public Ejemplo2(String prueba){
        System.out.println("Dentro del constructor del objeto");
        this.test=prueba;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Ejemplo2 prueba = new Ejemplo2("4");
    System.out.println("Lo que seria la primera linea del programa pero DESPUES de que se instancie el objeto de la clase");
    }
}

Output:
Bloque estatico 1
bloque estatico 2
Dentro del constructor del objeto
Lo que seria la primera linea del programa pero DESPUES de que se instancie el objeto de la clase
```

Espero que esto te ayude dado que puedes crear metodos dentro de esos bloques estaticos! Suerte con tu proyecto

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que lo que te explique estaba un poco mal. Esos bloques eran de instancias, no estaticos. Para que sean estaticos y corran antes de nada(nada mas inicies el programa incluso antes de que instancies un objeto de la clase) tienes que poner la palabra static enfrente de los bloques de codigo. Perdon por la confusion!

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, aun no he probado el código que me has facilitado pero tengo una duda, debido a que la aplicación que estoy desarrollando es una app web no tengo un metodo  main en el lado del servidor, en el servidor solo tengo los servicios web los que se conectan con sus respectivas clases para hacer las tareas asignadas  !! si entiendo bien si pongo un static block en una de las clases ese código se ejecutará automáticamente cuando despliegue la aplicación si necesidad de instanciar un objeto de esa clase?? espero tu respuesta gracias

Comment: Si efectivamente o eso creo. No tengo ni idea the Servidores webs y lo siento por tardar tanto en responder!